# Cannot instantiate service class interface while running API in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api

***THIS IS THE ERROR:***

```
"Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface SimplifiedMagento\\Custom2\\Api\\PositionRepositoryInterface in \/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/Magento2_3\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:50\nStack trace:\n#0 \/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/Magento2_3\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create('SimplifiedMagen...')\n#1 \/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/Magento2_3\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest\/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(90): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get('SimplifiedMagen...')\n#2 \/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/Magento2_3\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest.php(188): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n#3 \/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/Magento2_3\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#4 \/Applica' in '\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/Magento2_3\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php' on line 50"
```

Comment: Have you create di for your PositionRepositoryInterface if not, please create one and compile your code, if you still face the same issue please share your di.xml code

Comment: di.xml file:      <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
   <preference for="SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Api\Data\PositionInterface" type="SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Model\Data\Position" />
   <preference for="SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Api\PositionRepositoryInterface" type="SimplifiedMagento\Custom2\Model\PositionRepository" />
  
    
    </config>

Comment: your di.xml looks fine, try to delete your generated directory and run di:compile again.

Comment: Should i delete the generated directory or inner files of generated directory?

Comment: i am ruuning the API on POSTMAN. Do i need to make any changes in POSTMAN before running the API?

Comment: Please delete generated directory and run di:compile command

Comment: Did that but still the error is same.

Comment: Are you getting this error during di:compile or calling any specific class if yes, please share your complete code for more debugging

Comment: I am getting this error while running the API

Comment: Resolved that issue but now this error is coming:

Comment: (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5def5fbf16330; Message: Each method must have a doc block. See SimplifiedMagento\\Custom2\\Api\\PositionRepositoryInterface::getDetails() at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Magento2_3/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Each method must have a doc block.

Comment: please check if you have added the docblock before the function definition in API as well as in Model, please check this links for reference https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/coding-standards/docblock-standard-general.html if you still face the same issue, the same issue address here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/271048/magento-2-2-3-1-each-method-must-have-a-doc-block-see-magento-eav-api-attri

Comment: Thanks buddy!!!! it ran

Comment: comments was the issue

Comment: Welcome, please give up vote to last comment.